# Avoiding Python Off-by-One Error in RLE Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, off-by-one

EDIT: there's more wrong with this than just an off-by-one error, it seems.

I've got an off-by-one error in the following simple algorithm which is supposed to display the count of letters in a string, along the lines of `run-length encoding`.

I can see why the last character is not added to the result string, but if I increase the `range` of `i` I get `index out of range` for obvious reasons.

I want to know what the conceptual issue is here from an algorithm design perspective, as well as just getting my code to work.

Do I need some special case code to handle the last item in the original string? Or maybe it makes more sense to be comparing the current character with the `previous` character, although that poses a problem at the beginning of the algorithm?

Is there a general approach to this kind of algorithm, where current elements are compared to previous/next elements, which avoids index out of range issues?

```
def encode(text):
    # stores output string
    encoding = ""
    i = 0

    while i < len(text) - 1:
        # count occurrences of character at index i
        count = 1
        while text[i] == text[i + 1]:
            count += 1
            i += 1

        # append current character and its count to the result
        encoding += text[i] + str(count) 
        i += 1

    return encoding

text = "Hello World"
print(encode(text))
# Gives H1e1l2o1 1W1o1r1l1
```

Comment: You're using the same counter (`pos`) for the outer loop and for the inner loop - that's a very bad idea, especially since the outer loop is a `for in range` loop. Might work if you use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: Also, why are you incrementing `pos` at the end of the outer loop?

Comment: Because I changed the outer loop from `while` to `for`. I will edit now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you should have `while i < len(text)` for the external loop to process the last character if it is different for the previous one (`d` in your case).

Your algorithm is then globally fine, but it will crash when looking for occurrences of the last character. At this point, `text[i+1]` becomes illegal.

To solve this, just add a safety check in the internal loop: `while i+1 < len(text)`

```py
def encode(text):
    # stores output string
    encoding = ""
    i = 0

    while i < len(text):
        # count occurrences of character at index i
        count = 1
        # FIX: check that we did not reach the end of the string 
        # while looking for occurences
        while i+1 < len(text) and text[i] == text[i + 1]:
            count += 1
            i += 1

        # append current character and its count to the result
        encoding += text[i] + str(count) 
        i += 1

    return encoding

text = "Hello World"
print(encode(text))
# Gives H1e1l2o1 1W1o1r1l1d1
```

Comment: `while i + 1 < len(text)` So simple and obvious in hindsight. Yet brilliant, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your strategy, you'll have to check `i+1 < len(text)`.
This gives something like:

```
def encode(text): 
    L = len(text) 
    start = 0 
    encoding = '' 
    while start < L: 
        c = text[start] 
        stop = start + 1 
        while stop < L and text[stop] == c: 
            stop += 1 
        encoding += c + str(stop - start) 
        start = stop 
    return encoding
```

Another way to do things, is to remember the start of each run:

```
def encode2(text): 
     start = 0 
     encoding = '' 
     for i,c in enumerate(text): 
         if c != text[start]: 
             encoding += text[start] + str(i-start) 
             start = i
     if text:
         encoding += text[start] + str(len(text)-start) 
     return encoding
```

This allows you to just enumerate the input which feels more pythonic.